# How to implement "more" option?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a list in share point containing some news data including images. I need to show an image and a portion of news with "more" link, from which user will be able to open the entire news page. How can we implement that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way here is very straightforward. Create new field "ShortContent", add it to your view and hide it from the DisplayView. If news are created by content manager, than he should fill this field by himself, as it provides more pleasant view of "ShortContent".
The "more" link can be added in Event Receiver.

If you need to cut news automatically, than it can also be implemented in Event Receiver, but sometimes it can be complicated. You have to think about the algorithm and use some 3d-party HTML parser to properly cut images and text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you provide a sample code or link to do this ?